# How can I change add to cart button to backorder in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

On my wordpress site, I have variable products that are set to backorder, however on the product pages and single product pages, the buttons are still showing as add to cart. I expected these to have changed to Backorder, so customers don't waste their time.

We have logical reasons to keep those products display on site rather than hide them.

Would anyone be willing to fix this for me for a fee?

- Replace text with backorder, and also replace button color.